# Are these bounded regions the same in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is the region bounded by $y=\sqrt{x},y=2$ and $x=4$ the same by that bounded by $y=\sqrt{x},y=2$ and $x=0$?

For me, both are the region just above $y=\sqrt{x}$ and below $y=2$ for $0\leq x\leq4$.

Comment: If we're talking about real numbers, then yes, because if $y= \sqrt x$, $x$ must be greater than or equal to $0$; otherwise, $y$ is not defined.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, it's a question about simple integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about real numbers, then yes, because if $y= \sqrt x$, $x$ must be greater than or equal to $0$; otherwise, $y$ is not defined.  And $y= 2$ requires that $x= 4$.

In essence, for real $x$, each description relates to the same integral.

Comment: -1 vs accepted answer!!! Weird and creepy action!